# Correct format to sink to BigQuery using Dataflow Apache Beam

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It seems like an error occur in **bcdate**, and I transform it to correct format but the error is still here, my code is below:

```
def transform_pandas(data):
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    import datetime as dt

    df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    
    # Fill all columns with null if there is no data    
    columns = ['peakid', 'route1', 'bcdate', 'pkname', 'heightm']
    df = df.reindex(columns, fill_value='null', axis=1)
    
    df['bcdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bcdate'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    return json.loads(df.to_json(orient = 'records'))
```

and code to write to BigQuery:

```
output = (
        (input_p1, input_p2)
        | 'Join' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
        | 'Final Dict' >> beam.Map(lambda el: to_final_dict(el[1])) >> it got a result here
        | 'Transformation' >> beam.Map(transform_pandas) >> the error happen in here
        | beam.Map(print)
        | 'Write To BigQuery' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
           table='project:dataset.expeditions',
           # schema='peakid:STRING,route1:STRING,bcdate:DATETIME,pkname:STRING,heightm:INTEGER',
           method='FILE_LOADS',
           custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://bucket/folder/temp',
           create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)    
    )
```

Here is my result

- [{'peakid': 'ACHN', 'route1': '', 'bcdate': None, 'pkname': 'Aichyn', 'heightm': '6055'}]
- [{'peakid': 'AGLE', 'route1': 'null', 'bcdate': None, 'pkname': 'Agole East', 'heightm': '6675'}]
- [{'peakid': 'KCHS', 'route1': 'NW Ridge', 'bcdate': '2019-10-24', 'pkname': 'Kangchung Shar', 'heightm': '6063'}]
- [{'peakid': 'LNAK', 'route1': 'SSE Ridge', 'bcdate': '2015-09-17', 'pkname': 'Lhonak', 'heightm': '6070'}]
- [{'peakid': 'SPH1', 'route1': 'S Face', 'bcdate': '2017-04-14', 'pkname': 'Sharphu I', 'heightm': '6433'}]
- ...

But I got the error when I'm trying to sink to BigQuery:
**BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_329_215864ba592a2e01f0c4e2157cc60c47_3a904aab56c3444bb56bda650a7404b3 failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto
location: 'gs://bucket/folder/temp/bq_load/1d12aed0bdcc463aa5350cf2cca2ef2e/project.dataset.expeditions/d67ef933-d15a-45b0-8df5-e2b5a217849d'
message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://bucket/folder/temp/bq_load/1d12aed0bdcc463aa5350cf2cca2ef2e/project.dataset.expeditions/d67ef933-d15a-45b0-8df5-e2b5a217849d'
reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'Write To BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs']**

Comment: Hi @Nhu Dao, For all load jobs sent to BigQuery, you need to set the load configuration, which contains a schema for the data to be [loaded](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.schema). For JSON,you can either specify this schema, or use auto-detect. 
  If a schema is specified in the config, it is always used to read the data and if not specified, BigQuery uses the table schema to read the JSON data. If the JSON data doesn't match with the table schema, this error can occur. Can you check the schema of both the JSON data and BigQuery table?

Answer (score 0):

Your `bcdate` has the following date format `YYYY-MM-DD` in the result `Dict` but in your `Bigquery` schema and table you have a `datetime` type.

You can the check the doc to pass the correct format for `datetime` : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions?hl=en

For example :
`2017-05-26T00:00:00`

You can also find the info on the `beam` documentation :

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/

Example :

```json
bigquery_data = [{     
'string': 'abc',     
'bytes': base64.b64encode(b'\xab\xac'),     
'integer': 5,     
'float': 0.5,     
'numeric': Decimal('5'),     
'boolean': True,     
'timestamp': '2018-12-31 12:44:31.744957 UTC',     
'date': '2018-12-31',     
'time': '12:44:31',     
'datetime': '2018-12-31T12:44:31',     
'geography': 'POINT(30 10)'  
}]
```

Comment: I'd changed bcdate to this: 
```
df['bcdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bcdate'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

but the error is still here

Comment: Can you test without the `:%SZ` part => `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M` ? On my side I tested : `2017-05-26T00:00:00` and `2021-11-15 21:37:37` and this work

Comment: Hi @NhuDao, did the above comment help?

Comment: Hi @MazlumTosun, I have tested it but still not working. I got the result like that: => - [{'peakid': 'AGLE', 'route1': 'null', 'bcdate': None, 'pkname': 'Agole East', 'heightm': '6675'}]
- [{'peakid': 'AMAD', 'route1': 'SW Ridge', 'bcdate': '2020-01-27T00:00', 'pkname': 'Ama Dablam', 'heightm': '6814'}]. But it still got the error when writing to BigQuery

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, the issue is still here. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/

```bigquery_data = [{
    'string': 'abc',
    'bytes': base64.b64encode(b'\xab\xac'),
    'integer': 5,
    'float': 0.5,
    'numeric': Decimal('5'),
    'boolean': True,
    'timestamp': '2018-12-31 12:44:31.744957 UTC',
    'date': '2018-12-31',
    'time': '12:44:31',
    'datetime': '2018-12-31T12:44:31',
    'geography': 'POINT(30 10)' 
}]```

Comment: Your format is not good, try with `'datetime': '2018-12-31T12:44:31'` please. 
You used the following format : `2020-01-27T00:00`

Comment: Keep us informed please, normally it works :)

Comment: I tried the format: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S and it's still not working :(

Comment: Can you test with harcorded date time '2018-12-31T12:44:31' ?

Comment: I also test it, hmm.. when I remove bcdate fields, the error is still here. I reckon there is an error in somewhere else

Comment: In your example I saw 'heightm' field as String in result and as Integer in the schema : 'heightm': '6070'. Can you set the same type please and test it again ?

Comment: Yep, I also change it schema='peakid:STRING,route1:STRING,bcdate:DATETIME,pkname:STRING,heightm:STRING' but it still got the same error. I have no idea :(

Comment: I just saw an issue in your results, instead of having a `PCollection` of element, you have a `PCollection` of list. You need to flatten your result. Instead of having : `[{'peakid': 'ACHN', 'route1': '', 'bcdate': None, 'pkname': 'Aichyn', 'heightm': '6055'}]` you must have `{'peakid': 'ACHN', 'route1': '', 'bcdate': None, 'pkname': 'Aichyn', 'heightm': '6055'}`

Comment: I worked as PCollection of list before and it run well. So I don't think it was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `unknown_columns-- pcollection` is having unknown columns ..for file loads we cannot set `ignore_unknown_columns=True` in `writetobigquery`